# How can I cover grout lines and gaps against cabinetry and base trim?

Tags: tile, grout, caulking, caulk

In the picture below I have an area of my floor that is finished.
However on different parts of the floor, the last owner never finished portions of the floor.

It looks like they just extended the grout(i think its grout) to parameters of the tile.
My original idea was just to get caulk and to fill in the areas needed, but wasn't sure how close the color match would be. To give a little back story I'm on a concrete slab, and bugs like to crawl in the unfinished portions of the floor, so I'd like to seal off the cracks not only for looks.

My question is what route would you take in order to get the most consistent looking finish to complete the rest of my floor? Not sure what route to go, and how to get the colors to align. They don't need to be perfect, but hopefully something close.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a kitchen or a bathroom?

Comment: The original owner half finished the job in the living room, kitchen, and bathroom. The one in the picture above is the kitchen.

Answer (score 3):

Since this looks like a kitchen, the easiest route is to buy some trim (toenail, or quarter round) and nail that to the baseboard (goes faster with a nail gun and some 2.5" nails). Paint it white first, fill the nail holes, and goodbye wall gaps. Add some white caulk to the top to hide the seam.

For a bathroom I would spend a bit more and install vinyl quarter round (won't rot if it gets water trapped).

If nailing isn't your thing, could do it with construction adhesive, but you'll have to full demo the stuff if you ever want to replace the flooring.

Comment: We call it "base shoe". For retrofit tile installations it's standard practice. Ideally the door casings would've been undercut, but....